# array for loop, looping too many times javascript

Tags: javascript

Instead of looping through one time to show

```
id1
id2
id3
```

it loops through 3 times before stopping. what can i put to make it loop through only once.

html:

```
<p id="show_me"></p>
<button onclick="ObjectArray()">click me</button>
```

javascript:

```
var ObjectArray = function() {
        // object literal
        var id1 = {
            firstName: "John",
            lastName: "Doe",
            id: "12345"
        };

        // keyword new
        var id2 = new Object;
        id2.firstName = "Adam";
        id2.lastName = "Bakely";
        id2.id = "abcdef";

        // object constructor 
        function employee(first, last, id) {
            this.firstName = first;
            this.lastName = last;
            this.id = id;
        }
        var id3 = new employee("Dallas", "Star", "abc123");

        //create an array
        var IdArray = [id1, id2, id3];

        //for loop to display results
        var text="";
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < IdArray.length; i++){
            text += IdArray[0].firstName + " " + IdArray[0].lastName + " " + IdArray[0].id + "<br>";
            text += IdArray[1].firstName + " " + IdArray[1].lastName + " " + IdArray[1].id + "<br>";
            text += IdArray[2].firstName + " " + IdArray[2].lastName + " " + IdArray[2].id + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("show_me").innerHTML = text;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It iterates three times, because you loop for the length of the array, which has 3 items.

If you want to 'iterate' once, you can just omit the for loop:

```
text += IdArray[0].firstName + " " + IdArray[0].lastName + " " + IdArray[0].id + "<br>";
text += IdArray[1].firstName + " " + IdArray[1].lastName + " " + IdArray[1].id + "<br>";
text += IdArray[2].firstName + " " + IdArray[2].lastName + " " + IdArray[2].id + "<br>";
```

But I think you actually wanted to do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < IdArray.length; i++){
    text += IdArray[i].firstName + " " + IdArray[i].lastName + " " + IdArray[i].id + "<br>";
}
```

That way you use the loop what it's for: Iterate over an array of *any* length and repeat a piece of code for each item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything from the for loop, and add this instead:

```
text += IdArray[i].firstName + " " + IdArray[i].lastName + " " + IdArray[i].id + "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Every thing is fine ... but please replaced the following code

```
 for (i = 0; i < IdArray.length; i++){
        text += IdArray[i].firstName + " " + IdArray[i].lastName + " " + IdArray[i].id + "<br>";
        text += IdArray[1].firstName + " " + IdArray[1].lastName + " " + IdArray[1].id + "<br>";
        text += IdArray[2].firstName + " " + IdArray[2].lastName + " " + IdArray[2].id + "<br>";
    }
```

with

```
for (i = 0; i < IdArray.length; i++){
        text += IdArray[i].firstName + " " + IdArray[i].lastName + " " + IdArray[i].id + "<br>";

    }
```